# Replacing contenteditable text on the fly

Tags: javascript, contenteditable

I want to add some HTML as users type things into a contenteditable.  For example,

```
$('body')
  .delegate('div[contenteditable=true]', 'blur keyup paste',
    function(){
      var html = this.innerHTML;
      html.replace( "a", "b" );
      this.innerHTML = html;
    });
```

Well for one, this doesn't appear to replace anything.  Two, I get a weird issue that I can no longer type into the contenteditable div.  I checked events fired on the div, there is no 'blur' event going off.  I seem to have the div highlighted, but I have to click on the div again to type anything.  What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to allow the user to select things and make them bold/italic (or insert a block of HTML where the user's insertion point marker is), you want to use `document.execCommand`. The Mozilla website has [documentation on this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/rich-text_editing_in_mozilla).

Answer (score 1):

For the first part, the problem is that the `replace()` method of string in JavaScript returns a new string and does not affect the original string. What you need is:

```
html = html.replace("a", "b");
```

For the second issue, the problem is likely the fact that setting the `innerHTML` property of an element destroys and recreates the entire DOM tree within the element, and since the selection or caret was contained within that DOM tree that no longer exists, the browser has to do something to recover. My guess is that the browser you're testing in simply clears the selection.

Comment: Yeah I already thought replace was used this way, thanks for pointing it out.  Something does happen to the DOM tree when innerHTML is invoked not sure of what, but it's clear that they do not intend you to use it in the way that I am.

Answer (score 0):

Fighting with similar problem: I need to highlight some special characters in contenteditable. For example, highlight & nbsp; with red background. So I'm doing something like

```
elem.innerHTML = elem.innerHTML.replace('&nbsp;', '<span class="highlight">&nbsp;</span>');
```

Of course browser will recreate elem (to redraw it) and elem will loose focus and caret position. If you'll print elem.innerHTML on keyup/input event in FireFox you'll see it pastes special < br > as a marker. I'm trying to use same technique: I'm pasting marker at caret position using Range object, then I'm replacing & nbsp; (at this point I loose focus) and then I'm getting marker to select it and delete.

See Range API docs https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/range